# Can't render a triangle with D3D12

Tags: directx-12, direct3d12

I want to render a triangle with D3D12, but it doesn't function. I followed the Direct 3D Programming Guide by Microsoft.

I can clear the render target view and in the output I become a COMMAND_LIST_DRAW_VERTEX_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL warning (DrawInstanced: Vertex Buffer at the input vertex slot 0 is not big enough for what the Draw*() call expects to traverse...) every frame. So my thought is, the problem is at the vertices, coping  the vertices.

Here is my code:

```cpp
struct Vertex {
    float x;
    float y;
};

const Vertex vertices[] = {
    { 0.0f, 0.5f },
    { 0.5f, -0.5f },
    { -0.5f, -0.5f }
};

const UINT vertexBufferSize = sizeof(vertices);

// Create and load the vertex buffers
// I'm using an upload heap, because I can't find any solution about a default heap.
CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES vertexBufferHeapProperties(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD/*D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT*/);
auto vertexBufferResourceDesc = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(vertexBufferSize);

THROW_IF_FAILED(m_pDevice->CreateCommittedResource(
    &vertexBufferHeapProperties,
    D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
    &vertexBufferResourceDesc,
    D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ/*D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_SOURCE*/,
    nullptr,
    IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pVertexBuffer)
));

// Copy the vertex data to the vertex buffer
UINT8* pVertexDataBegin;
CD3DX12_RANGE readRange(0, 0);
THROW_IF_FAILED(m_pVertexBuffer->Map(0, &readRange, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pVertexDataBegin)));
memcpy(pVertexDataBegin, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
m_pVertexBuffer->Unmap(0, nullptr);

// Create the vertex buffer views
m_vertexBufferView.BufferLocation = m_pVertexBuffer->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
m_vertexBufferView.SizeInBytes = sizeof(Vertex);
m_vertexBufferView.StrideInBytes = vertexBufferSize;
```

In the input layout I'm using a DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT and D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA for position.

And in the PopulateCommandList function:

```cpp
const float clearColor[] = { 0.6f, 0.7f, 0.9f, 1.0f };
m_pCommandList->ClearRenderTargetView(renderTargetViewHandle, clearColor, 0, 0);
m_pCommandList->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
m_pCommandList->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_vertexBufferView);
m_pCommandList->DrawInstanced(3, 1, 0, 0);
```

Comment: If you are new to DirectX generally, you should probably start with [DirectX 11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). If you are familiar with DirectX 11 and just moving to DirectX 12, you may find the [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
m_vertexBufferView.BufferLocation = m_pVertexBuffer->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
m_vertexBufferView.SizeInBytes = vertexBufferSize;
m_vertexBufferView.StrideInBytes = sizeof(Vertex);
```

instead of

```
m_vertexBufferView.BufferLocation = m_pVertexBuffer->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
m_vertexBufferView.SizeInBytes = sizeof(Vertex);
m_vertexBufferView.StrideInBytes = vertexBufferSize;
```